# How to find end of bag file while reading it in an external application

Tags: python, deep-learning, image-segmentation, realsense

I am using RealsenseL515 to record a bag file and im later using that file and performing instance segmentation on it. The repo metioned here [segmentation](https://github.com/ErikGDev/instance-segmentation) has provisions to read bag file of the realsense data and run inference on it. However, when i run main.py and pass bagfile to it, it keeps rereading the file on infinite loop and I am unable to stop when its finished reading it once. I want to save the output of the inference as an mp4 and hence need to know when the entire bag file has been processed once. How do i do this?

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? I have the same issue. Thanks